# Set-AzureStorageBlobContent hangs at 100% in Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-rm

I have a powershell script that generates a pdf report from an ssrs server, after the file is created there's no locks in it as im able to move it or email it as an attachment etc during testing.

When my script trys to upload the file to azure it hangs at 100%, i checked azure and the file is in there but still sits at 100% in powershell.

Any ideas?

Code below, i havn't included the function code for generating the report as its pretty long winded.

```
GenerateReport -ReportFile $FullFilePath -StartDate $StartDate -EndDate $EndDate| Out-Null

$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$files = Get-ChildItem $BaseFolder -Recurse
foreach($file in $files)
{

$blobfile = "Epsom/$($file)"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $File.FullName -Container $ContainerName -Context $context -Blob $blobfile -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. Do you get errors?

Comment: No errors if i remove -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue, works the same and hangs at 100% still.

p.s sorry for late reply as i wasnt notified of the comment